# How to use $(this) in $(this), on Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('.element').each(function(){
  $(this).load('file.php',function(){
    $(this).show(); // this row is not working
  });
});
```

**or**

```
$('.element').each(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).show(); // this row is not working
  },1000);
});
```

Comment: the "this" keyword points to the current object.In your cases, both of the ajax & timeout functions execute their code in a different scope, where "this" does'n point to your initial object anymore.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479247/jquery-unable-to-fade-out-a-previously-faded-in-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.load('file.php',function(){
        $this.show();
    });
});
```

or:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $this.show();
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: thenks, but "$this = element1" on each while 1
and "$this = element2" on each while 2
settimeout runing element2 not run element1

Answer (score 0):

you need to save it in a variable or pass into inner function

```
$('.element').each(function(){
  var outerObj = this;
  $(this).load('file.php',function(){
    $(outerObj).show(); // this row is not working
  });
});
```

Comment: thenks, but outerObj element[0] in 1th each, outerObj element[1] in 2th each.. how fix this problem

Comment: `myArr[0]` will always return the first element of an array (jQuery selectors return an array, too), `myArr[1]` will return the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) transfer object inside to other scope.